# How do I do a "Is Required" test on text field?

Tags: asp.net, xml, server-side

I'm trying to make a registration form for a ASP.NET project, it has to include a "Is Required" test for each field. Anyone have any good resources on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is WebForms you can use RequiredFieldValidator.  Here is a simple example that would valid a text box named "txtName":

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txtName"
        ErrorMessage="User ID is required."> *
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Here is an MSDN article that talks about exactly what you want and gives examples of other validators (again, assuming this is WebForms):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx

And a code project article with more examples and info:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334310/Understanding-ASP-NET-Validation-Techniques